# Is it possible to form a square using sheets of $A4$ sized paper (without them overlapping)?

Tags: geometry, analysis

Any sheet of A series paper has an irrational number as its aspect ratio; $\sqrt2$. My intuition tells me that there is no way to combine these sheets of paper into a square without them overlapping — but I can't find any way on how I would go about proving this. Anybody got any idea?

Comment: How can the aspect ratio possibly be irrational? "Ratio" is even in the phrase; it's $W/H$. Just take the LCM of the width and height and form a square of that size. A4 paper is $210mm × 297mm$ the LCM of which is $20,790$, so you could form a square by arranging $99$ of them by $70$ of them, which would take $6,930$ sheets of paper. I must be missing something obvious for this not to be the answer. I don't know where $\sqrt2$ has come from in particular.

Comment: @DaveCousineau: The $\sqrt{2}$ factor that appears for A0-A8 paper has to do with the silver ratio, preserving aspect ratios, and for manufacturing simplicity related to the mathematics. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_ratio#Paper_sizes_and_silver_rectangles) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216#Application). The term "ratio" does not mean rational. In your example, $W$ and $H$ need not be integers; $W/H$ will still be their ratio.

Comment: @EricNaslund thanks, although that still seems kind of iffy. you can't literally construct a physical sheet of paper that has $\sqrt2$ length. a real sheet of paper will have a rational length or width, and you will be able to arrange them in a square.

Comment: @DaveCousineau : Is your position that no one can cut a square piece of paper along its diagonal?

Comment: @DaveCousineau, While you cant even *measure* to see if your physical sheet is $\sqrt{2}$ in length, you can still *try* (within the tolerances your machinery allows you). To see where the $\sqrt{2}$ comes from read up more about its history... Also, for fun, fold a corner of an A sized sheet at 45deg so that it meets it's adjacent edge, now hold up the resultant hypotenuse to another sheet's longer edge. Look like they're about the same size??

Comment: @LamarLatrell $\sqrt2$ requires infinite precision. In practice, only a small amount of precision is necessary. Maybe the nearest $mm$, for example. Even if you take it to the extreme, the paper is made of a finite and integral number of molecules. $\sqrt2$ would require *fractional molecules*. In practice, there is no infinite precision, and lengths are never irrational. As a physics question, it is definitely possible to make a square out of A4 paper. (I do understand that this is not asked as a physics question.)

Comment: @DaveCousineau If you're going to use argument from physics then you haven't thought about many things. Firstly, even though a paper is made of integral number of molecule, the way those molecule align is also not in a perfect straight line so that reasoning is invalid. To play the devil's advocate even further, you cannot measure the exact length of a paper due to the uncertainty principle (and quantum fluctuation, too) so it cannot be determined physically if the length of paper is rational or irrational.

Comment: (continued) Your argument rest on faulty assumptions about physical nature of molecules and, more importantly, how rational/irrational number ought to behave. For some reason you seems to think that by default if things cannot be proven to be irrational it must be rational. That is absurd and not logical in anyway. Mathematically speaking, the set of rational has measure zero on real line so if we are to take a random length of something (whatever that means), you're more likely (100% to be exact) to find out that the length is of irrational quantity (assuming some fixed unit length).

Comment: @BigbearZzz Even if the length was irrational (whatever that could possibly mean), you couldn't measure it because it requires infinite precision. *In practice* the length will always be rational and you will always be able to form a square to some degree of non-infinite precision.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Measuring at molecular distances being absurd is exactly the problem. $\sqrt2$ requires *infinite* precision. That means precision beyond molecular distances, and even precision beyond the planck length (in fact infinitely more precise than that). It doesn't even mean anything to be that precise.

Comment: @DaveCousineau I don't even know why you keep saying "in practice" or "precision" or "physical" in a _mathematics_ Q&A website, where things are defined in mathematical terms. The arguments you try to sell are metaphysics at best. Irrationality has a precise meaning in mathematics, not just some arbitrary notion whose existence is just for word-playing purpose. There ARE theorems with real-life consequences whose proof or statement rely on irrationality of certain numbers, numerous actually. Your disbelieve in their existence does not invalidate its usefulness.

Comment: Seeing how you seem to be interested in computer-related stuff, I am baffled by your view on irrational numbers. Do you think also that it's not fruitful to view or think about number as object with "infinitely precise" just because computer can store floating numbers with only finite precision? Do you know Fourier transform? Do you know how coefficients of wavelets are computed?

Comment: Putting all that aside and back to the main problem. I could care less about if it's meaningful or not to be able to "measure" the actual length of a paper physically, my main concern is that you defaulted to "since it's absurd for things to be irrational, it must be rational". You could say that it's either rational or irrational and I'd probably agree. You could say that the length can't be determined physically and I'd agree even more. However, for some reason you think that irrational requires infinite precision while rational number _do not_, this I cannot agree to.

Comment: @BigbearZzz The reason I keep saying "in practice" is because the conclusion that is drawn here is *wrong*. You can, in fact, create a square out of sheets of A4 paper. Your point about rational numbers needing infinite precision too is interesting, but it doesn't matter. The point is that you cannot be infinitely accurate. The square will be an imprecise square and the sheets of paper will have estimations of $\sqrt2$. You mention computers. Note that computers are not theoretical, and have these same kinds of limitations of *needing to really exist*.

Comment: @DaveCousineau Mathematically, a square need to have _exactly_ the same length for each side. If you want to talk about an approximate square then sure, we can build that. Your argument is wrong mathematically, which is what really matters here. If we pretend that we are talking about approximate square then your argument is trivial and I cannot think of anyone here who would disagree to that.

Answer (score 38):

Suppose this was possible.

We have used $n$ number of sheets (say, A4) to do this. The area of each sheet is $\sqrt2$ (let us consider each sheet of dimensions $1 \times \sqrt 2 $).

Total area of sheets $= n\sqrt 2$.

Now let $a$ be the number papers whose short side makes a boundary on any particular side, and $b$ be the number of papers whose long side is involved in that particular boundary.

Side length of square $l = a \times 1+b \times \sqrt 2$.

Now equate the area of square to $n\sqrt 2$.

We've $$n\sqrt 2= l^2 =(a+b\sqrt 2)^2$$
Thus, $$\sqrt 2 = \frac{a^2+2b^2}{n-2ab}$$

Which isn't possible, obviously, since $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

Therefore leading to a contradiction. Hence, our assumption was false.

**Thus, there cannot exist a square consisting of vertically and horizontally placed A4 papers.**

Comment: Like Mark's answer, you answer doesn't include the proof that there cannot exist a square consisting of vertically and horizontally placed A4 papers.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Both solutions are perfectly fine.

Comment: This answer is interesting, but it does not appear to be complete. In general, 'a' and 'b' are not necessarily the same for all sides. (For a trivial case, imagine making a square out of 1:2 rectangles. By rotating pairs of rectangles, you could make cases where no two sides of the square have the same number of long/short sides...)

Comment: @TLW It suffices to consider any one side (or in fact any cross section parallel to any side)

Comment: @ThePirateBay: This *is* a proof.

Comment: Wouldn't we have to show first that this proof applies to any one combination of sides by showing that if we take two sides of a square, say $r = x*a + y*b$ and $s = k*a + l*b$  that it follows from $y = l$ that $x = k$ because in our equation above we have the possibility of $n - 2ab = 0$?

Comment: this is only true in theory, not in practice

Comment: @math_mu No, we do not need to, but if you want to, you can.Taking any one side is sufficient. As of your query about $r$ and $s$, we can conclude $x=k$ and $y=l$ if $a$is an irrational number of the form $\sqrt{\lambda} \; \lambda \in \Bbb N$, and $b$ is an integer, or vice versa. Also, $n=2ab$ isn't possible, since it'll imply (from just the equation above that line) that $a^2+2b^2=0 \implies a=b=0$, which makes no sense. *By the way you do not need to unaccept the answer if you have some doubt related to the solution, you could have just pinged me by commenting*.

Answer (score 15):

For completeness' sake, as with much mathematics, what we might assume in theory doesn't always hold in reality; a model can only go so far in telling us what can or cannot happen.

A4 paper has dimensions defined as 210mm by 297mm. These are both divisible by 3, so that the ratio is 70:99.

70 lengths are equivalent to 99 widths. If a grid of sheets are aligned edge to edge and corner to corner, they can be used to make a square without overlaps or gaps.

Comment: Just to emphasize the difference between theory and practice. "A4 paper has dimensions defined as 210mm by 297mm. These are both divisible by 3", AS PER STANDARD ISO 216, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216#A_series. Otherwise we have $ 2^{1/4}/4 $ and $ (1/(2^{1/4}))/4 $ giving 297.302.... and 210,224...., so ratio is $sqrt2$

Comment: @cgiovanardi What are your “otherwise” numbers based on? What standard exists in the world where A4 is defined as having sides like $2^{1/4}/4$?

Comment: I mean that in theory we have an aspect ratio of SQRT(2). But in practice the aspect ratio is 99/70, as @Nij stated in his answer.

Comment: For those wondering why [ISO 216](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216) uses the ratio $\frac{99}{70}$ to specify A4 paper, note that it is the [sixth convergent in the continued fraction expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Continued_fraction_representation) of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I have reverted [an edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2537185/revisions) by user StephenG, that had edit summary “Expand on explanation of why sqrt(2) is not the correct ratio for A4 paper”. The reason is that the edit was longer than this answer itself; so it's up to the author of this answer to incorporate it if they choose.

Comment: The two downvoters could try to explain what they dislike about the answer. Is it just the fact that problems exist in the context of the real world, and I burst the bubble of total abstraction, or did I not use enough MathJax to keep them happy? Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: This seems to me better as a comment than as an answer, since the question clearly concerns ideal A-series sheets with “_aspect ratio;_ $\sqrt 2$”; I suspect that this explains most of the downvotes.

Comment: But the A-series does not have an irrational aspect ratio, it is *by definition* a rational ratio. Talking about an idealised form of things that exist in the real world when a) they make no sense and b) could just as easily have been posed as an abstract problem, requires an answer pointing out the issue with the assumption made. @PJTraill

Answer (score 12):

Here is a sketch.

If units are chosen so the sides of the paper rectangle are $1$ and $\sqrt 2$, the side of the square is $a+b\sqrt 2$ and considering a corner we must have $a,b \gt 0$.

Now the area of the square is $(a+b\sqrt 2)^2=a^2+2b^2+2ab\sqrt 2$

The area of an individual rectangle is $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

Comment: You didn't prove that there cannot exist a square consisting of vertically and horizontally placed A4 papers.

Comment: @ThePirateBay I assumed the side of the square has $a$ vertical and $b$  horizontal. I am implicitly using that if $a+b\sqrt 2 = c+d\sqrt 2$ then $a=c$ and $b=d$ which follows from irrationality. Alternatively if there is a square with all orientated the same, I can rotate it and make a square with $a,b\gt 0$ which is all in need, because $a^2+2b^2$ is not an integer multiple of $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: What about if the sides do not have the same 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: @TLW It is a square - I can either use what was in my previous comment, or simply that the sides are equal because it is a square.

Comment: @MarkBennet - it being a square does _not_ imply, in general, that all sides have the same number of 'short' sides. Consider the case of making a square out of 2 1:2 rectangles.

Comment: @TLW But If one side is $a+b\sqrt 2$ so is the other, however it is composed, because it is a square.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more powerful theorem that solves this problem. First, we have to show that the component rectangles have sides parallel to the sides of the entire rectangle.

**Lemma:** If there is a polygon whose sides are axis-aligned and that can be subdivided into rectangles, then the component rectangles are axis-aligned.

**Proof:** By induction on the number of component rectangles. The case with one component rectangle is obvious. Now assume there is more than one. There must be at least one 90° angle (in fact, there must be at least four). The only way to cover this angle is with the corner of one of the rectangles, and this rectangle must also be axis-aligned. If you remove that rectangle, you'll be left with one or more smaller polygons, each with only 90° and 270° angles.

**Theorem:** Suppose a rectangle can be divided into multiple rectangles, where each rectangle has at least one side of integral length. Then the original rectangle has at least one side of integral length.

**Proof:** Consider this function from the plane to the complex numbers: $$f(x, y) = e^{2\pi i(x + y)}$$
If you integrate $f$ over an axis-aligned rectangle $[x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]$, you get $${(e^{2\pi i x_2} - e^{2\pi i x_1})(e^{2\pi i y_2} - e^{2\pi i y_1})}\over{-4\pi^2}$$ This vanishes if and only if at least one of the dimensions is an integer. The integral over the entire rectangle is the sum of the integrals over the components, so the integral over the entire rectangle is zero, so at least one of the sides is an integer. □

Therefore the square has integral side length, and the area is also integral. But the area is also equal to $n\sqrt{2}$, where $n$ is the number of sheets. But this is irrational, a contradiction.

Comment: I can‘t quite see how you can directly exclude cancellation of nonzero terms in your last step?

Answer (score 1):

Another generalization. You can't tile a square with a (finite) mix of (virtual) $An$-dimensional sheets. To prove that, use the smallest sheet in the mix to tile the others and invoke any of the other proofs here.

This argument is for the virtual paper (where $A(n+1)$ is what you get by halving $An$) since (as another answer points out) [real $An$ paper dimensions](http://www.papersizes.org/a-paper-sizes.htm) are integral numbers of millimeters.